# How to get data from the model

Tags: python, django, view, model

I need to get data from a model in Django. I specify filtering, an error occurs. I'm doing a project with TV series and movies. When clicking on any of the listed categories, I need to take data from this category. That is, which films belong to this category.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Zi7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8vgb.png)

I am trying to fix this problems but it didnt help me

Comment: if you got any errors add them to your question

Comment: Please do not post the image of source code or data. It is hard to reproduce the problem with that. Sample source code to reproduce the problem always helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your situation well. But that's what I did when I was in that situation.

```
def gallery(request):
    category = request.GET.get('category')
    if category == None:
        photos = Photo.objects.all()
    else:
        photos = Photo.objects.filter(category__name=category)
        
    categorys = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'categorys':categorys,
        'photos':photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'photos/gallery.html', context)
```

[Making queries about more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal. Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users, so providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.